# Natural Language Programming

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying different ways of approaching: https://www.kaggle.com/aaron7sun/stocknews 
The below code gives this error: "ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')"

```
    import panda as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup             
import re
import nltk
nltk.download()
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/s7c/Documents/Untitled Folder/Combined_News_DJIA.csv/Combined_News_DJIA.csv") 
data.info()

def news_to_words(reddit_news):
    # 1. Remove HTML
    newstxt = BeautifulSoup(reddit_news).get_text() 
    #remove non-letters
    ltrs = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', newstxt)
    #convert to lower case/split into individual words
    wrd = ltrs.lower().split()
    #In Python, searching a set is much faster than searching
    #   a list, so convert the stop words to a set
    st = set(stopwords.words("english"))                  
    #Remove stop words
    meaningful_words = [w for w in wrd if not w in st]   
    #Join the words back into one string separated by space, 
    # and return the result.
    return(" ".join( meaningful_words)) 

train = data[data['Date'] < '2015-01-01']
test = data[data['Date'] > '2014-12-31']

#method of combining all headlines
train_comb=train.iloc[:,2:27].apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(row.values)), axis=1)
test_comb=test.iloc[:,2:27].apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(row.values)), axis=1)

new_train_comb = []
for i in range(0, len(train_comb)):
     new_train_comb.append(news_to_words(train_comb))
```

The error comes when I try to iterate over the function...
Any help much appreciated

Comment: What is `words`?

Comment: Please provide a more descriptive title. Regardless, you meant *natural language processing*, which isn't the same thing as *natural language programming*.

Comment: Also, this is a common error. Did you try googling it? What did you find? Did it help? If not, how did it fail to help? This is not a debugging service. You need to provide some more effort to a question than just dumping your code and an error message.

Comment: Why do you think I meant "natural language processing"? "Did you try googling it? What did you find? Did it help? If not, how did it fail to help? " Maybe this is not a debugging device but it's not a place for dogmatism and demagogy either

Comment: as I said the error appears when I compile the function and probably it would have helped mentioning that it related to boolean condition which needs to be approached in a more optimum manner. But not having a very deep understanding of the programming field I don't know how could I change my function it order to avoid the error...with this comment I complete every constructive idea which comes into my mind...

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake. I forgot the iteration factor over the train_comb series

```
new_train_comb = []
for i in range(0, len(train_comb.index)):
     new_train_comb.append(news_to_words(train_comb[i]))
```